# How search special characters in Kibana

Tags: kibana

I would like to find messages which contains this sequence "--->", but Kibana result it's wrong.

How escape this characters to have a good result ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should be checking your `mappings`, whether your fields are not marked as `not_analyzed` (or don't have keyword analyzer). If it happened to be there as such you won't be able to see any search results. Standard analyzer removes characters when indexing a document.

What if you search it within the quotes including your special character?

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566838/elastic-search-hyphen-issue-with-term-filter) could help you. You could also maybe have a look at the `Special Characters` section at the [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) doc. Hope it helps!