# elasticsearch / kibana, search for documents where message contains '=' char

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i have an issue which i suspect is quite basic but i have been stuck on this for too long and i fear i am missing something so basic that i can't see it by now.

we are using the ELK stack today for log analysis of our application logs.
logs are created by the JAVA application into JSON format, shipped using filebeat into logstash which in turn processes the input and queues it into ES.

some of the messages contain unstructured data in the message field which i currently cannot parse into separate fields so i need to catch them in the message field. problem is this:
the string i need to catch is: "57=1" this is an indication of something which i need to filter documents upon. i need to get documents which contain this *exact* string.

no matter what i try i can't get kibana to match this. it seems to always ignore the equal char and match either 57 or 1.

please advise.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may check the Elasticsearch mapping on the field type of the referring field. If it is analyzed, the '=' may not have been indexed due to the default-analyzer. ([source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242343/how-search-special-characters-in-kibana), [source 2](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-search-for-special-characters/41453))