# IllegalArgumentException when using FieldType.keyword on @Id field with spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a simple ES document that is annotated with Spring elastic search:

```
@Document(indexName = "indexName", type = "metadata")
public class EsMetadata {

    @Id
    @NonNull
    @Field(type = FieldType.keyword)
    String metadataId;

    @NonNull
    @Field(type = FieldType.keyword)
    String assetId;
}
```

Those two strings usually are represented by a UUID string, which includes hyphens. When trying to search for a specific UUID i run into this problem mentioned here: [Elastic Search Hyphen issue with term filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566838/elastic-search-hyphen-issue-with-term-filter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The solution (or workaround) is to set the FieldType to `keyword` works on the `assetId` field, but not on the `metadataId` field - apparently because it is marked as `@Id`.

When I call `this.esTemplate.putMapping(EsMetadata.class)` I get a few IllegalArgumentExceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert [metadataId.index] to boolean
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse value [not_analyzed] as only [true] or [false] are allowed.
```

I use `9515882b-f583-4675-bc19-44c9247c0365` and `bc205f3e-35c2-f583-835c-344a9f89d758` as sample UUIDs where parts are equal to correctly test the desired behaviour.

When I remove the `@Field(type = FieldType.keyword)` annotation from `metadataId`, everything works fine - except that I get duplicates upon searching for specific `metadataId` UUIDs. For `assetId` UUIDs there are no duplicates - as expected.

How can I use the `keyword` FieldType on an `@Id` annotated field, so i can look up specific UUIDs? Or did I run into a bug?

I use spring-data-elasticsearch 3.1.0.M1 and Elasticsearch 6.2.2